# Antlr4 parsing templateLiteral in jsx

Tags: reactjs, parsing, jsx, antlr, antlr4

I have tried to use grammar defined in grammars-v4 project(https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/javascript/jsx) to parse jsx file.
When I parse the code snippet below,

```
let str =
        `${dsName}${parameterStr ? `( ${parameterStr} )` : ""}${returns ? `{
${returns}}` : ""}`;
```

it shows the following error

```
 line 2:32 at [@8,42:42='(',<8>,2:32]:no viable alternative at input '('
```

https://astexplorer.net/ shows it is a TemplateLiteral with conditionalExpression inside, any thoughts for parsing such grammar?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Thanks @Bart, it works.

**It works fine on the following code.**

```js
const href1 = `https://example.com/lib/downloads_${page}.htm?joinSource=${joinSource}${inviter?`&inviter=${inviter}`: ''}`;

const href2 = `https://example.com/act/kol/detail_${this.props.values.list.res.rows && this.props.values.list.res.rows[0].id}_${page}.htm?joinSource=${joinSource}${inviter?`&inviter=${inviter}`: ''}`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given Mike's observation that it's the template string that is messing things up, here's a quick solution:

Changes:

### JavaScriptLexerBase.java

Add the instance variable:

```
// Keeps track of the the current depth of nested template string backticks. 
// E.g. after the X in:
// 
// `${a ? `${X
//
// templateDepth will be 2. This variable is needed to determine if a `}` is a 
// plain CloseBrace, or one that closes an expression inside a template string. 
protected int templateDepth = 0;
```

### JavaScriptLexer.g4

```
// Place TemplateCloseBrace above CloseBrace!
TemplateCloseBrace: {this.templateDepth > 0}? '}' -> popMode;

...

// Remove (or comment) TemplateStringLiteral
// TemplateStringLiteral:          '`' ('\\`' | ~'`')* '`';

BackTick
    : '`' {this.templateDepth++;} -> pushMode(TEMPLATE)
    ;

...

// Place at the end of the file:
mode TEMPLATE;

BackTickInside
    : '`' {this.templateDepth--;} -> type(BackTick), popMode
    ;

TemplateStringStartExpression
    : '${' -> pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE)
    ;

TemplateStringAtom
    : ~[`]
    ;
```

### JavaScriptParser.g4

```
singleExpression
    : ...
    | singleExpression templateStringLiteral    # TemplateStringExpression  // ECMAScript 6
    | ...
    ;

literal
    : ...
    | templateStringLiteral
    | ...
    ;

templateStringLiteral
    : BackTick templateStringAtom* BackTick
    ;

templateStringAtom
    : TemplateStringAtom
    | TemplateStringStartExpression singleExpression TemplateCloseBrace
    ;
```

I did not fully test my solution, but it parses your example input successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bart. It works, appreciate your help!

Comment: You're welcome @MarkZhao. It was because of MIke's answer that I had another look at it :)

Comment: So… maybe you could have gotten by with holding your breathe :). Nicely done Bart.  It had not occurred to me that the nested backticks were necessarily inside the interpolation logic allowing them to be distinguished,  (To keep the token nodes down, shouldn’t TemplateStringAtom be “![`]+” ?)

Comment: @MikeCargal thanks, but `~[\`]+` would consume `${...`

Comment: @BartKiers, ah yeah, guess I shouldn’t make suggestions without verifying them :)

Comment: I found a case that doesn't work. See edit section. @BartKiers

Comment: @MarkZhao hence my remark about it being a "quick solution": I've not fully tested it. Feel free to try to give it a shot yourself, and if you get stuck, you can always ask a question here. Also, what does "doesn't work" mean exactly? Does the parser produces some sort of error? If so, also post the error. A quick test on my side resulted in both your new examples parsing just fine.

Comment: @BartKiers My bad. It works just fine. I made a mess on my local branch.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the ANTLR grammar shows:

```
// TODO: `${`tmp`}`
TemplateStringLiteral:          '`' ('\\`' | ~'`')* '`'
```

So, apparently, it’s on the “TODO List”.   Allowing nested “`” string interpolation is surprising (to say the least), and will be “non-trivial” for the ANTLR Lexer (So, I would not "hold my breather" waiting on a fix for this).

Have you tried: (replacing the nested “`”s with “‘s?).

```
let str =
        `${dsName}${parameterStr ? “( ${parameterStr} )” : ""}${returns ? “{
${returns}}” : ""}`;
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply. What I need is parse the code without making any modifications on the source code. Just curious about how to parse the nested string interpolation. It's not like standard tags(e.g. HTML) which have unambiguous opening and closing symbols.