# antlr4: how to define string grammar for javascript in velocity file?

Tags: javascript, antlr4, velocity

I have tried to use grammar defined in grammars-v4 project(https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/javascript) to parse js file, and I have merged velocity grammar,but i can not define a grammar that can recognize string or vm reference, like this:

```
func.method("$val.method("val")")
func.method("$value")
func.method("${value}")
func.method("${value}abcdefg")
```

like question in [Antlr4 parsing templateLiteral in jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618203/antlr4-parsing-templateliteral-in-jsx/67623671#67623671), I defined grammar like this:

parser:

```
dirtyStringLiteral
    : DoubleQuote_ dirtyStringAtom* DoubleQuote_
    ;

dirtyStringAtom
    : DirtyStringAtom
    | vmReference
    | DirtyStringStartExpression singleExpression DirtyCloseBrace
    ;
```

lexer:

```
DirtyCloseBrace: {this.templateDepth > 0}? ')' -> popMode;

DoubleQuote_
    : '"' {this.templateDepth++;} -> pushMode(DIRTYSTR)
    ;
mode DIRTYSTR;

DoubleQuoteInside
    : '"' {this.templateDepth--;} -> type(DoubleQuote_), popMode
    ;

DirtyStringStartExpression
    : ('$'| '$!') -> pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE)
    ;

DirtyStringAtom
    : ~["]
    ;
```

but the vm can end with or not end with ')', so how can i defined a grammar for this?
@Bart Kiers

Comment: What is your goal? Parsing Velocity templates?

Comment: Thank you Bart.When I parsed a vm file, I encountered some different writing methods(displayed in my question), they are all nested in <script></script>. but ```func.method("$identifier.method("str")")```
has not been  parsed correctly,when I follow you in https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/ , but the new problem I encountered is that func.method("$vm_val") cannot be parsed correctly because it starts with ‘$’, but it is not End with‘)’. My goal is to find a grammar that can correctly parse all vm strings nested in js, and can parse the vm references correctly.

Comment: 1. can you post your complete grammar? 2. I assume the JavaScript  does _not_ have `$`'s embedded in strings? E.g. all the `$`'s  are Velocity meta chars?

Comment: Anyway, this is  the JavaCC grammar responsible for parsing Velocity templates: https://github.com/apache/velocity-engine/blob/master/velocity-engine-core/src/main/parser/Parser.jjt . Perhaps easier if you use that. Or you could try converting it into ANTLR (not trivial, by looking at all the different lexical modes in the JavaCC grammar!). Good luck!